# Using kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation for non-navigation

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Accuracy_Constants) states that using `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` is only recommended for navigation applications, and only when plugged in, due to the additional battery usage.

I'm developing an application that only needs location periodically, perhaps even only once per app load, to find the user's location to display them some nearby places to choose from. So I don't need it often, but when I need it, it needs to be really accurate (and obviously as quick as possible). My desire is to try and get to 10m accuracy (or better) as quickly as possible.

If I use `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`:

1. Will this have any meaningful impact on the battery when used for a short period of time (measured in seconds)? Or is Apple's conservative guidance aimed at people using this accuracy level for long periods of time?
2. Perhaps of more importance, does this level of accuracy lead to longer wait times when the location manager first starts up? I.e. wait time before first reasonably accurate locations are reported?
3. Is there any documentation of the technical differences between `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` and `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`? I.e. what is happening exactly that allows the former to be more accurate?

Answer (score 4):

1. I really doubt it. Do this this experiment. Assume that it does have a significant impact on battery life. How could an app that uses best accuracy not kill your phone in very little time if running the GPS for a short period of time had a significant drain on the battery? It can't unless the best accuracy GPS had a significant startup battery drain and then used less power afterwards. I doubt it does that, but now do this experiment. Run your app with the GPS on full and monitor your battery usage. Run a controlled experiment, fresh reboot, maybe even a clean phone. Observe how battery % lowers over time. My guess is that it is linear with a great drain for greater accuracy.
2. I've used a hybrid approach before, using kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer for the initial coarse location determination. When that comes in, I change to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation to refine the location. This lets you have a quick response, usually under 0.5 seconds for the coarse accuracy, then you can get a better reading a few seconds (often around 3 in my testing) later.
3. I have no idea what apple is doing but my experience from geocaching might help. A good hand held GPS averages its readings over time. So you might start out with 50 ft accuracy and then if you stand still and collect more readings they get averaged. This reduces your statistical error.

Comment: I have also used #2 approach in this use case with success. Note the CLLocation returns an accuracy value, so you can track accuracy in your delegate, and call `stopUpdatingLocation()` once you reach desired accuracy (or a time limit).